# Subqueries on subqueries

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, subquery

I'm trying to create a select statement

I need to gather from one table a record that equals the same code used in another table.

better put, a client selects from a drop down list a city and a category for that city.
When the client clicks next, the various places in that city that meet that category are displayed.
but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

now when the client selects a city, there are two records that read for each city, a proper city code and a post box code that has 'bx' as the first letters

in my first query, to eliminate duplicates, I say

```
select c.[Description] from city c 
where c.Provincecode like 'EC' and 
      c.citycode in (select c.citycode from City c 
                     where SUBSTRING(c.citycode,0,3) not like 'bx')
```

that gives me one city name.

but now, if the client has chosen, for instance, cash only places to see,
there should only be one record showing up in the results

but try as I might, I can't get the right syntax

I've tried:

```
select c.[Description] from city c 
where c.Provincecode like 'EC' and 
      c.citycode in (select c.citycode from City c 
                     where SUBSTRING(c.citycode,0,3) not like 'bx') 
      and exists (select * from Customers cu 
                  where cu.Category like 'SC' and cu.Province like 'EC')
```

but that brings more results than anticipated

this is done using an access database, but I am using SQL to do the coding, which I re-write into access. that's not a problem

so if someone could please provide the SQL answer, I can do the rest from there

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do a join.
I did try

```
select * from 
(select c.[Description] from city c 
 where c.Provincecode like 'EC' and 
       c.citycode in (select c.citycode from City c 
                      where SUBSTRING(c.citycode,0,3) not like 'bx')) x 
join Customers on  province=city.provincecode where Category like 'SC'
```

but I get errors for multi-part identifier could not be bound

---

EDIT

this is the new query

```
select * 
from 
    (
        select c.* 
        from city c 
        where c.Provincecode like 'EC' 
            and c.citycode in
                (
                    select c.citycode 
                    from City c 
                    where SUBSTRING(c.citycode,0,3) not like 'bx'
                )
    ) x 
    join 
    Customers  
        on  province=x.Provincecode 
where Category like 'SC'
```

what is returned is 
[image]

as you can see, there are too many reults that have C Strydom as the customer, but all the cities are there

for this particular example, only one record should be shown, the second one
[image]

Comment: In your last query the JOIN condition includes `city.provincecode` but `city` is not in play: that JOIN is between the `Customers` table and the derived table you've aliased as `x`.

Comment: ok. I changed the select c.{Description] to c.*, said x.Provincecode (derieved from table) and sort of worked. distinct will give me one, without, I get 12 results.

Comment: how do I refine it from there? (sorry for misspelling on earlier comment)

Comment: It's hard to say without some representative sample data or other additional information. It sounds like you're looking to return one record and (I think) you said that adding a `DISTINCT` returned one record, so was it not the right one?

Comment: no. if I didn't use distinct, from the above sample I would get 12 records. only one is correct. but somewhere, a clause is returning all records. using distinct would eliminate the extras of course, but for future use, I would like to see what is causing the extras. I need to place the like clause somewhere, just can't spot where

Comment: You might get better assistance if you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17105276/edit) your question to show some representative sample data, the updated version of your query, what it returns, and what your desired result is.

Comment: updated. thanks for the help so far

Comment: What makes 'JBay' the "right answer"?

Comment: in the db, it is the only record for the field province/code EC that has the category SC. all the others in the results should have G H as their categories. so, JBay should be the correct choice

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused because the second query in your question tries to filter by `cu.Category like 'SC'` where `cu` is an alias for `Customers`. So do both the `City` and the `Customers` tables have `Category` columns, and can they both contain 'SC'?

Comment: sorry. no. only the customers table has category. the similar fields the tables share are province/code which would be JBay in both tables

Comment: ...so perhaps you need something like `... ) x INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.province=x.Provincecode AND Customers.city=x.Citycode ...` ?

Comment: perfect. works. make it an answer so its done

Comment: I have posted my answer. Glad to hear it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an incomplete JOIN (see question comments for details). The query that worked was

```
select * 
from 
    (
        select c.* 
        from city c 
        where c.Provincecode like 'EC' 
            and c.citycode in
                (
                    select c.citycode 
                    from City c 
                    where SUBSTRING(c.citycode,0,3) not like 'bx'
                )
    ) x 
    INNER JOIN 
    Customers 
        ON Customers.province=x.Provincecode 
            AND Customers.city=x.Citycode 
where Category like 'SC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't like using SELECT *, you know more of the actual columns you DO want, I leave that to you.  The query should be simple as you are primarily looking at the "City" table for a specific province code but doesn't start with "bx".  Just have that in your where clause... you can test multiple things about a record without having to join to itself on some other criteria.  Once you have that, then a simple join to the customer table for the category you are limiting to.

```
select *
   from 
      city c 
         JOIN Customers CU
            on c.ProvinceCode = CU.Province
           AND CU.Category like 'SC'
   where 
          c.ProvinceCode like 'EC' 
      and NOT substr( c.CityCode,0,3 ) = 'bx'
```

Now, your issue of the multiple records per customer.  If all you are joining on is the province code to the customer table, you WILL get a Cartesian result... but if you join to the ProvinceCode AND City of the customer, you'll get only the single one that matches... but we don't have the customer table detail to confirm that column relationship.