# Syntax errors in MS Access converting from SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join, syntax-error

From my earlier question 
[subqueries-on-subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105276/subqueries-on-subqueries)

I'm now trying to put this into access

The code is from answer one on the link, copied and pasted exact with the exception of putting left(citycode,2) and not substring(citycode,2)

trying to run this I now get syntax errors.

the first was the *Syntax Error in Join Operation*

Did some research and changed the code. Then came *JOIN expression not supported*

I read this article ["JOIN expression not supported" error caused by unbracketed JOIN expression comprising string condition](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468)

And now I think I've got it narrowed down to *Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'province = x.provincecode and customers.city = x.citycode where category like 'SC'*

Now this all works in SQL. I need to use it in access as my db is .mdb.
The output should be just one line:
[image]

I don't know where the error is in my statement

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * from City  where Provincecode like 'EC' and citycode in 
(select citycode from city  where left(citycode,2) not like 'bx')) 
as x inner join customers on (province = x.provincecode and
customers.city=x.citycode where category like 'SC')
```

As I said, this works in SQL, and it gets one line of code.
But when it comes to access, it goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this (I have no data to check):

```
SELECT * 
from (
    SELECT * 
    from City  
    where Provincecode like 'EC' and citycode in (
        select citycode 
        from city  
        where left(citycode,2) not like 'bx'
    )
) as x 
inner join customers on customers.province = x.provincecode and customers.city=x.citycode
where x.category like 'SC'
```

You have no need for parenthesises here, you have used only single join. If you had more joins, then general syntax would be:

```
select ...
from ((
    table1
    join table2 on ...)
    join table3 on ...)
    join table4 on ...
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the following as a query:
    SELECT * from City  where Provincecode like 'EC' and citycode in 
(select citycode from city  where left(citycode,2) not like 'bx')

Then write a second query joining the first query with the customers table

BTW: When you use LIKE you must use wildcard characters such as * or ?

Comment: sorry. could you please elaborate. I tried *SELECT * from Query1  inner join customers on (province like provincecode and customers.city like citycode where category like 'SC')*. is this right? sorry, have not used access is ages. customer wants access db

Comment: You should be doing it using the Access Query Designer. That way Access will write the SQL syntax for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you carry out the first sub-select on the city table to apply the second clause, I may have overlooked something, but does this query suffice:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM City As A, Customers As B
WHERE A.Provincecode like 'EC*'
AND Left(A.citycode, 2) not like 'bx*'
AND B.category like 'SC*'
AND B.province = A.provincecode
AND B.city = A.citycode
```

Comment: @NicholasAysen I'm not sure why you have moved the acceptance around, I was also trying to help you by demonstrating there was no need for the nested sub-query you had, it's worth understanding SQL and learning best practice as generally sub-queries will slow performance.